# Regex expression to check for alphanumeric string does not work

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to test if my String contains a character ( a-z) (A-Z) and a number (0-9)

```
package testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Testing extends JPanel 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String foo = "abc1";

        if (foo.matches(".*[0-9].*") && foo.matches(".*[A-Z].*") && foo.matches(".*[a-z].*"))
        {
            //contain letters and numbers only
            System.out.println("Foo");
        }


    }


}
```

I am expecting **Foo** to be printed out but there seems to be a problem with my regex expression. Can someone help me out ??

Thanks

Comment: your `foo` doesn't match `foo.matches(".*[A-Z].*")`

Comment: Do the characters have to appear before the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
foo.matches(".*[0-9].*") && foo.matches(".*[A-Z].*") && foo.matches(".*[a-z].*")
```

to

```
foo.matches(".*[0-9].*") && (foo.matches(".*[A-Z].*") || foo.matches(".*[a-z].*"))
```

Comment: You don't need the .* before and after the `[]` since the expression is not being anchored at the start or end of the source string.

Comment: @Jason - Yes he does need them.  `matches` matches the entire expression, not a substring.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `foo.matches(".*[A-Z].*")` will return `false`, as there are no capital letters in `foo = "abc1"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.matches(".*([0-9]+).*") && foo.matches(".*([a-zA-Z]+).*")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will identify a match in one regex:

```
foo.matches(".*([0-9].*[a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z].*[0-9]).*")
```

Comment: No, it matches strings that have a letter anywhere before a number or a number anywhere before a letter. I didn't use ^ or $ so it is not anchored to the start or end of the source string.

Comment: Why .*? (.*) itself means 0 or more, no need of ?

Comment: @TejasPatel ? means reluctant grab. In this case it isn't required.

Comment: I am unclear for the fact that he just wants to match `a-z A-Z 0-9`

Comment: @hwnd Read the first line of the question. "I am trying to test if my String contains a character (a-z) (A-Z) **and** a number (0-9)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single expression instead of multiple as follows -

```
if (foo.matches("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*")) {
    //...
```

That will make sure that `foo` contains at least one of the alphabets (lower or capital) and at least of the digits.

Comment: What's the performance of this expression like?  I have a suspicion it might run very slowly on large strings.

Comment: How large strings are we talking about?

Comment: I don't know.  It was just a question.  I've seen regular expressions similar to this one running into problems, when the string being matched was only a dozen characters or so.  It would be interesting to test this.

Comment: Seems like http://myregextester.com/ is a good online tool for the purpose. You can test the pattern `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$` there with different inputs of your choice and see the results.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following Regex for Alpha Numeric...

```
foo.matches("\\w.*")
```

Or

```
foo.matches("\\w+");
```

Comment: " ... contains a character **AND** a number ... "